# WebGL - Invalid Operation useProgram

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm learning WebGL and am on [this](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=684) tutorial that has to do with lighting. I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not so good at debugging it yet. I keep getting these errors, anyone know why I'm getting them and how to fix it?

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid http://insanergamer.zxq.net/:1
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked http://insanergamer.zxq.net/:1
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked http://insanergamer.zxq.net/:1
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf 8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="gl-matrix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="first.js"></script>

        <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
               precision mediump float;

                varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
                varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

                uniform sampler2D uSampler;

                void main(void) {
                    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
                }

        </script>

        <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
            attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
            attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

            uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
            uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
            uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

            uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

            uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
            uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;

            uniform bool uUseLighting;

            varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
            varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
                vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

                if (!uUseLighting) {
                    vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                } else {
                    vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
                    float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
                    vLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
                }
        </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="webGLStart()">
    <header>
    </header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <h3><a href="todo.html">Link to the TODO page.</a></h3>

        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="lighting"></input>Lighting On/Off<br />
            Ambient Lighting Color: Red:<input type="text" id="ambientR"></input> Green:<input type="text" id="ambientG"></input> Blue:<input type="text" id="ambientB"></input> <br />
            Light Direction: X:<input type="text" id="lightDirectionX"></input> Y:<input type="text" id="lightDirectionY"></input> Z:<input type="text" id="lightDirectionZ"></input> <br />
            Direction Lighting Color: Red:<input type="text" id="directionalR"></input> Green:<input type="text" id="directionalG"></input> Blue:<input type="text" id="directionalB"></input> <br />
        </form>

        <p>Press 'F' to change Texture quality.</p>
        <p>Use Arrow Keys to rotate cube.</p>
        <p>Page Up and Page down to zoom in and out.</p>
        <canvas canvasProperties="prop" id="canvas1" style="border: none;" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
        <article>
            <header>
            </header>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

**first.js**

```
    var gl;
function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
}


function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}


var shaderProgram;

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

    shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
    shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
    shaderProgram.useLightingUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uUseLighting");
    shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientColor");
    shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uLightingDirection");
    shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uDirectionalColor");
}

var cubeTextures = Array();
function initTexture()
{
    var cubeImage = new Image();

    for(var i=0;i < 3; i++)
    {
        var texture = gl.createTexture();
        texture.image = cubeImage;
        cubeTextures.push(texture);
    }

    cubeImage.onload = function()
    {
        handleLoadedTexture(cubeTextures);
    }
    cubeImage.src = "cube.png";
}

function handleLoadedTexture(texture)
{
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture[0]);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[0].image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[1].image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture[2].image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var mvMatrixStack = []
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function mvPushMatrix()
{
    var copy = mat4.create();
    mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
    mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
}

function mvPopMatrix()
{
    if(mvMatrixStack.length == 0)
    {
        throw "No Matrix to Pop!";
    }
    mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
}

function degToRad(degrees)
{
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}
function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);

    var normalMatrix = mat3.create();
    mat4.toInverseMat3(mvMatrix, normalMatrix);
    mat3.transpose(normalMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform, false, normalMatrix);
}

var cubeVertexPositionBuffer;
var cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer;
var cubeVertexIndexBuffer;

function initBuffers() {

    cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
    vertices = [
       // Front face
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

      // Back face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

      // Top face
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

      // Bottom face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

      // Right face
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

      // Left face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    cubeVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 24;

     cubeVertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexNormalBuffer);
    var vertexNormals = [
        // Front face
         0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.0,  0.0,  1.0,

        // Back face
         0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
         0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
         0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
         0.0,  0.0, -1.0,

        // Top face
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,

        // Bottom face
         0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
         0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
         0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
         0.0, -1.0,  0.0,

        // Right face
         1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         1.0,  0.0,  0.0,

        // Left face
        -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        -1.0,  0.0,  0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexNormals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    cubeVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    cubeVertexNormalBuffer.numItems = 24;

    cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    var textureCoords = [
         // Front face
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,

          // Back face
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,

          // Top face
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,

          // Bottom face
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,

          // Right face
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,

          // Left face
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
    cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = 24;

    cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
    var cubeVertexIndices = [
      0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
      4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
      8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
      12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
      16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
      20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
    ]

    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    cubeVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
    cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;
}

var rCubeX = 0;
var SpeedX = 0;

var rCubeY = 0;
var SpeedY = 0;

var z = -5.0;

var filter = 0;

function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, z]);

    mvPushMatrix();
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rCubeX), [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rCubeY), [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, cubeVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTextures[filter]);
    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
    var lighting = document.getElementById("lighting").checked;
    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.useLightingUniform, lighting);
    if(lighting)
    {
        gl.uniform3f(
            shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientR").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientG").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientB").value)
        );
    }

    var lightingDirection = [
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightDirectionX").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightDirectionY").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightDirectionZ").value)
    ];
    var adjustedLD = vec3.create();
    vec3.normalize(lightingDirection, adjustedLD);
    vec3.scale(adjustedLD, -1);
    gl.uniform3fv(shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform, adjustedLD);
    gl.uniform3f(
        shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform,
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("directionalR").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("directionalG").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("directionalB").value)   
    );

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    mvPopMatrix();
}

var lastTime = 0;
function animate()
{
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if(lastTime != 0)
    {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

        rCubeX += (SpeedX * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        rCubeY += (SpeedY * elapsed) / 1000.0;
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}

 var currentlyPressedKeys = {};

 function handleKeyDown(event){
    currentlyPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
    if(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == "F"){
        filter += 1;
        if(filter == 3){
            filter = 0;
        }
    }
 }

 function handleKeyUp(event){
    currentlyPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;

 }
function handleKeys()
{
    if(currentlyPressedKeys[33])
    {
     z -= 0.05;
    }

    if(currentlyPressedKeys[34])
    {
        z += 0.05;
    }

    if(currentlyPressedKeys[37])
    {
        SpeedY --;
    } else if (SpeedY < 0){
        SpeedY ++;
    }

    if(currentlyPressedKeys[39])
    {
        SpeedY ++;
    }else if(SpeedY > 0){
        SpeedY --;
    }

     if (currentlyPressedKeys[38]) {
         SpeedX --;
    } else if(SpeedX < 0){
         SpeedX ++;
    }

    if (currentlyPressedKeys[40]) {
         SpeedX ++;
    } else if(SpeedX > 0){
         SpeedX--;
    }
}

function update()
{
    requestAnimFrame(update);
    handleKeys();
    drawScene();
    animate();
}


function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    initTexture();

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
    document.onkeyup = handleKeyUp;

    update();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cause in this particular case is that you're missing a closing } at the end of your vertex shader, though that doesn't answer why you aren't seeing a message about why your shader is failing to compile.

Your error checking code in `getShader` actually looks like it should work fine, and you do in fact check and alert the error logs Clutch mentioned when compilation and linking fails.

When I copied your code and ran it verbatim, it correctly gave me an error ("unexpected EOF"), so maybe you have javascript alerts turned off? You might consider using `console.log` instead of alerting and getting to know the Javascript console in your favorite browser.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue but just FYI, As long as linking fails for invalid programs GL is not required to return failure on compilation. :-(

Answer (score 4):

WebGL is giving you a big hint with the console log messages:

WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked

The program is not linked and therefore can't be used or it's state queried.

Your program does seem to be checking that the shaders compiled correctly and that the program is linked, but that's not the case. There is likely something wrong with your error checking code, hiding the real issue. I always call these two functions on freshly compiled shaders and recently linked programs:

getShaderInfoLog

getProgramInfoLog

They both return strings and will help you get to the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting these weird errors, but only in Chrome and not in Firefox:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked 
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid 
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked 
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked
```

I also noticed that most of the examples on http://threejs.org/ throw errors too (only in Chrome). And by redownloading the source, i was able to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use an updated version of three.js, e.g. from this CDN http://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js. Older versions throw the above errors on valid code.